# FormulaR1C1 including variable - Application-Defined Error: Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am attempting to do a calculation in Excel VBA but I get the error

> Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error

This is the code I am attempting to execute. The error happens on the line `.FormulaR1C1 = ...`, but I'm not sure why.

```
Function CalcNumDays()
Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, NoofDays As Variant
d1 = "01/01/2017"
d2 = "03/01/2017"

NoofDays = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(d1, d2)

With Sheets("ALL")
    With .Range("K2:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(SUM((RC[-8]+RC[-7]/RC[-4])*NoofDays,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

End Function
```

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: what line are you getting the error? and can  you post up a sample sheet or even an image of the sample sheet

Comment: @Miguel - the line that throws the error is the .FormulaR1C1 - I will edit to include an image of sample data

Comment: NoofDays must have a meaning in the spreadsheet and not in the variable to work in a FormulaR1C1 like this. check user3598756 answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(SUM(RC[-8]+RC[-7]/RC[-4])*" & NoofDays & ",0)"
```

Comment: You are welcome. As you might already have got, you had to "pass" the formula the actual value of  `NoofDays` and you had one parenthesis too much, too. Finally you may want to mark answer as accepted. thank you!

Comment: Good thing **noofdays** wasn't also a Defined Name on the worksheet or the original formula would have been accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is this line:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(SUM((RC[-8]+RC[-7]/RC[-4])*NoofDays,0)"
```

You want to include the variable `NoofDays`, so this must fall outside the string, concatenate strings using an ampersand `&`

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(SUM((RC[-8]+RC[-7]/RC[-4])*" & NoofDays & ",0)"
```

You were also missing a bracket to end the `SUM`, so final correction is

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(SUM((RC[-8]+RC[-7]/RC[-4])*" & NoofDays & "),0)"
```

Comment: -> your suggestion gives the same error as my syntax.